# Нужна ли точка в конце предложения с прямой речью?

Tags: прямая-речь

Работая на пленэре, он спрашивал у прохожих: «А какого цвета это здание?» или «А этот цветок, он розовый или синий?»

Или правильно:

Работая на пленэре, он спрашивал у прохожих: «А какого цвета это здание или этот цветок, он розовый или синий?»

На сайте "Тотальный диктант 2013" [приводится](http://totaldict.ru/upload/files/%D0%A2%D0%94%202013%20%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%201%20%D0%95%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0.pdf):

Академик И. П. Павлов писал, что «идея без развития мертва; стереотипность в научной мысли – гибель; барство – самый опасный яд».

Академик И. П. Павлов писал, что «идея без развития мертва; стереотипность в научной мысли – гибель...».

Академик И. П. Павлов писал: «Идея без развития мертва; стереотипность в научной мысли – гибель...»

В первом и втором случае точка, стоящая после закрывающих кавычек, относится ко всему предложению в целом; в третьем – цитата оформлена как самостоятельное предложение, имеющее свой собственный конечный знак (многоточие), поэтому после закрывающей кавычки точки нет.) [ПАС 2007: 308–309].

То же самое у Лопатина по ссылке:

http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137

Но у Розенталя (http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=167#pp167) случай, когда прямая речь заканчивается многоточием (по логике вопросительным или восклицательным знаком ), не рассматривается.

Впрочем, у Розенталя по адресу http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=167#pp167

пишется:

3)      после цитаты (перед закрывающими кавычками), когда цитируемое предложение приводится не до конца, например: Выступая в защиту культуры устной речи, Чехов писал: «В сущности ведь для интеллигентного человека дурно говорить должно бы считаться таким же неприличием, как не уметь читать и писать...»

2. После цитаты, заканчивающейся многоточием, ставится точка, если цитата не является самостоятельным предложением, например: М.В. Ломоносов писал, что «красота, великолепие, сила и богатство российского языка явствует довольно из книг, в прошлые века писанных...».

Судя по этим примерам, если прямая речь, то в конце предложения не ставится точка, а если цитата не является самостоятельным предложением - то ставится точка.

Хотя, как и у Лопатина, нет примеров, когда прямая речь заканчивается вопросительным или восклицательным знаком.

Лопатин (http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137):

§ 143. Цитата, включенная в авторское предложение на правах его компонента, выделяется кавычками (но начинается со строчной буквы), знаки препинания употребляются только те, которые диктуются самим авторским предложением: Мысль Л. Н. Толстого «время есть отношение движения своей жизни к движению других существ», высказанная в его дневниках, имеет философское содержание.
Если цитата не является самостоятельным предложением и заканчивается многоточием, то после закрывающих кавычек ставится точка, относящаяся ко всему предложению в целом: Искандер заметил, что «мудрость — это ум, настоянный на совести...». Ср.: Академик И. П. Павлов писал, что «идея без развития мертва; стереотипность в научной мысли — гибель; барство — самый опасный яд». — Академик И. П. Павлов писал, что «идея без развития мертва; стереотипность в научной мысли — гибель...». — Академик И. П. Павлов писал: «Идея без развития мертва; стереотипность в научной мысли — гибель...» (В первом и втором случае точка, стоящая после закрывающих кавычек, относится ко всему предложению в целом; в третьем — цитата оформлена как самостоятельное предложение, имеющее свой собственный конечный знак (многоточие), ПОЭТОМУ ПОСЛЕ ЗАКРЫВАЮЩЕЙ КАВЫЧКИ ТОЧКИ НЕТ.)

На сайте:

http://yermolovich.ru/board/1-1-0-88

рекомендуют ставить точку... и даже вопросительный знак:

Чтобы снять двусмысленность, абсолютно логично и даже необходимо маркировать эти варианты закрывающей пунктуацией, соответственно:

(a) Он не слышал, как она спросила: «Кто здесь?». 
(b) Он не слышал, как она спросила: «Кто здесь?»?

Мильчин же пишет:

11.7.3. Отсутствие знака препинания после закрывающих цитату кавычек
Знак препинания не ставится:
1. Если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит многоточие, восклицательный или вопросительный знак, а цитата, заключенная в кавычки, является самостоятельным предложением (таковы, как правило, все цитаты после двоеточия, отделяющего их от слов цитирующего). Например:
Печорин писал: “Я не помню утра более голубого и свежего!”
Печорин признавался: “Я иногда себя презираю...”
Печорин спрашивает: “И зачем было судьбе кинуть меня в мирный круг честных контрабандистов?”
То же, если самостоятельным предложением заканчивается цитата, первое предложение которой начинается со строчной буквы. Например:
Печорин размышляет: “...зачем было судьбе кинуть меня в мирный круг честных контрабандистов! Как камень, брошенный в гладкий источник, я встревожил их спокойствие...”
2. Если перед закрывающими цитату кавычками стоит вопросительный или восклицательный знак, а цитата не является самостоятельным предложением и после всей фразы с цитатой должен был бы стоять вопросительный или восклицательный знак. Например:
Лермонтов восклицает в предисловии, что это “старая и жалкая шутка!”

"Грамота" (http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_76):

в) не ставят никаких знаков, если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит многоточие, вопросительный или восклицательный знак, а заключенная в кавычки цитата является самостоятельным предложением (таковы, как правило, все цитаты после двоеточия, отделяющего их от предшествующих им слов цитирующего): 
Глава заканчивается словами: «Прощай, философия, прощай, молодость, прощай, Германия!»

Розенталь ():

4. Если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит вопросительный или восклицательный знак, то тот же самый знак не повторяется после кавычек; неодинаковые же знаки, если они требуются по условиям контекста, ставятся перед закрывающими кавычками и после них. Например: Читали ли вы статью в «Известиях» «Куда мы идем?» Ср.: Бойцы двинулись в атаку с криком «Вперед!». Когда был выдвинут лозунг «Вся власть Советам!»?

Бойцы двинулись в атаку с криком «Вперед!».

Глава заканчивается словами: «Прощай, философия, прощай, молодость, прощай, Германия!»

Разница между этими предложениями в том, что в первом случае нет прямой речи. Поэтому в конце точка. Во втором предложении - прямая речь. Поэтому нет точки.

Comment: _или_ не относится к прямой речи. Если бы был один вопрос, например:

Comment: Работая на пленэре, он спрашивал у прохожих: «А какого цвета это здание?»

Comment: то точка в конце предложения не нужна была бы. Но в первом варианте с двумя вопросами непонятно, что за структура предложения. И, соответственно, нужна ли в конце его точка.

Comment: Но "Грамота" рекомендует именно так:

Comment: Работая на пленэре, он спрашивал у прохожих: «А какого цвета это здание?» или «А этот цветок, он розовый или синий?»

Comment: Если было оформлено, как придаточное, а не прямая речь

Comment: Работая на пленэре, он спрашивал у прохожих «А какого цвета это здание?» или «А этот цветок, он розовый или синий?».

Comment: была бы вроде понятна логика расстановки знаков препинания.

Comment: Дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку на грамоту, конкретно на то место, о котором вы говорите. Там много всего говорилось - и противоречивого и просто взаимоисключающего.

Comment: ответ "Грамоты" можно найти по ссылке http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search_answer/?s=%D0%E0%E1%EE%F2%E0%FF+%ED%E0+%EF%EB%E5%ED%FD%F0%E5%2C+%EE%ED+%F1%EF%F0%E0%F8%E8%E2%E0%EB+%F3+%EF%F0%EE%F5%EE%E6%E8%F5%3A

Comment: Спасибо. Уточнение. Первое. Это мнение "Справочного бюро", оно не всегда совпадает с мнением редакции. Второе. Не указаны критерии, по которым точка не нужна. А это существенно. Я постараюсь найти одну (а может, и не одну) дискуссию на той же грамоте и/или других авторитетных ресурсах, просто не помню, где обсуждался именно подобный случай. Дальнейшее - смотрите текст моего ответа.

Comment: >То же самое у Лопатина по ссылке:  
  
>http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137 ---------------------- Если вы имеете в виду параграф 137, то та о другом. А "тотальный диктант" - источник совсем не авторитетный. Хотя здесь они пишут они в общем-то правильные вещи. Но только опять - вопрос применимости к конкретным случаям.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В ответе" Грамоты" написано "не требуется", но это не означает "нельзя ставить". Современные правила оформления прямой речи говорят: в утвердительном предложении после пояснения автора ставится двоеточие, затем в кавычках пишется реплика, в конце предложения ставится точка.

Пример:

*Андрей подумал: «Все авторы будут правильно оформлять прямую речь».*

В вопросительном или восклицательном предложении картина та же, но кавычки закрываются после вопросительного или восклицательного знака, и после кавычек точка не ставится, потому что восклицательный и вопросительный знаки выполняют двойную роль: это знаки конца предложения и знаки экспрессии речи.

Примеры:

*Андрей подумал: «Все авторы будут правильно оформлять прямую речь!»

Андрей подумал: «Все авторы будут правильно оформлять прямую речь?»*

Общий смысл предложений в прямой речи, а она - восклицательное и вопросительное предложения.

Если же в общем смысле предложения экспрессии нет, возможно поставить в конце предложения точку. Вы привели не всё предложение.

Автор - священник Георгий Чистяков. ВСТРЕЧА

*Дальтоник, он со временем превратился в исключительного мастера карандашного рисунка, и только в последние годы стал писать акварелью — работая на пленэре, спрашивал у прохожих, приводя их этим в полное замешательство: «А какого цвета это здание?» или «А этот цветок, он розовый или синий?».*

http://www.damian.ru/Actualn_tema/Chistakov/na_zare.html

Священники часто придерживаются старых правил пунктуации, до 1956 г., считают их более точными. Здесь достаточно длинное повествовательное предложение, поэтому он поставил точку.

Answer (score 2):

Спорный вопрос. Если Грамота дает конкретный ответ, то хорошо бы в этом случае привести и ссылку на авторитетный источник.

Я бы поставила точку, так как старшая структура предложения  определяется наличием однородных членов (две прямые речи), а прямая речь оформлена как две самостоятельные замкнутые единицы со своими знаками перед кавычками.

Работая на пленэре, он спрашивал у прохожих: «А какого цвета это здание?» или «А этот цветок, он розовый или синий?».

Вот, например, оформление встроенной прямой речи по тому же принципу:

Основной темой первой части сборника Блока «Ночные часы» является тема полнейшей безысходности, для которой характерна только «неизвестность, гибель впереди!».

Answer (score 1):

Ваш заголовок не соответствует вопросу.

Отвечаю на вопрос, заданный в тексте. Оба варианта возможны. Не очень понимаю, почему вы решили их противопоставить. Если "или" является частью прямой речи, то второй вариант, если нет, то первый.

Что до точки после прямой речи (требующей вопросительного или восклицательного знака), то вопрос тут достаточно дискуссионный. Скорее нужна, чем нет. Но я не буду подробно отвечать, пока не пойму, что вы спрашиваете именно об этом, чтобы не запутать все окончательно.

Вот первое, что попалось из того, что я помнил.
http://yermolovich.ru/board/1-1-0-88

> Резюмирую: в условиях неразберихи нужно отдать приоритет логике. Отсутствие точки в конце повествовательного предложения, включающего прямую речь или цитату, лишает предложение завершённости. Поэтому я в таких случаях рекомендовал бы точку всё же ставить, а при необходимости обосновать это ― ссылаться на §135 справочника Розенталя, тем более что и текст указаний §119 (если не считать реальной пунктуации примеров в этом параграфе) формально этому не противоречит.
>   (Подробности - по ссылке)

Автора нельзя отнести к общепризнанным авторитетам, но уверяю Вас, он говорит именно то, что и куда более непререкаемые авторы. Я еще поищу. Чуть позже.