# Пунктуация в предложениях с закрывающей кавычкой в конце

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

Было такое: [Нужна ли точка в конце предложения с прямой речью?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/415513/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C%D1%8E)

А тут будет больше конкретных предложений.

**Не «прямая речь»:**

1. Кир Булычёв защитил докторскую диссертацию по теме
   «Буддийская сангха и государство в Бирме».
2. Вы прочитали роман «Мечтают ли андроиды об электроовцах?».
3. Вы прочитали роман «Мечтают ли андроиды об электроовцах?»?
4. Неужели вы не читали роман «Мечтают ли андроиды об электроовцах?»!

**Прямая речь:**

5. Пётр спрашивает у андроида Фёдора: «Мечтают ли андроиды об электроовцах?» А у Ивана сенокос.
6. Пётр говорит Фёдору: «Ты забыл свою антенну».

**Ещё варианты с прямой речью:**

7. Пётр недоумевает: «Мечтают ли андроиды об электроовцах?».
8. Пётр кричит в бездну мироздания: «Мечтают ли андроиды об электроовцах?»!
9. Пётр спрашивает у андроида Фёдора: «Мечтают ли андроиды об электроовцах?»?

Пример (**5**) выглядит странно без точки, особенно после добавления второго предложения. Так точно верно?

Даже если считать, что (**9**) неверно, и нужно использовать (**5**), то непонятно, где грань между (**7**) и (**5**=**9**).

Верно ли (**3**)? Можно ли убрать второй вопросительный знак, как в (**5**)?

---

**UPD.**

В (**8**) мне не удалось передать идею, что восклицательными являются именно слова автора, а прямая речь просто вопросительная и может быть совсем не восклицательной. Так лучше:

8.1. Ух-ты, Пётр всё-таки спросил: «Ты выйдешь за меня?..»!

Пояснение по поводу (**2**) (**3**) — это 2 разных предложения: я либо констатирую факт, что вы прочитали роман, либо спрашиваю, прочитали ли вы роман.
(при вопросе будет восходящая интонация на `прочитали`, при утверждении `вы прочитали роман` будет произнесено ровно).
Если всё же корректная запись (**3**) превращается в (**2**), то как их различить на письме?

Та же самая идея скрывается за (**7**) (**9**) — я либо сообщаю о вопросительной прямой речи, либо спрашиваю о ней. Например, я переписываюсь с Иваном, и сообщаю ему следующее:

7.1. Пётр спрашивал у Фёдора: «Мечтают ли андроиды об электроовцах?».

Либо я переписываюсь с Иваном и спрашиваю у него следующее:

9.1. Пётр спрашивал у Фёдора: «Мечтают ли андроиды об электроовцах?»?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55430/discussion-on-question-by-yalov------).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Прямая речь**:

В предложениях с прямой речью знак конца предложения ставится один раз - точка после кавычек, вопросительный, восклицательный знаки и многоточие перед закрывающими кавычками, потому что он совпадает со знаком эмоциональной окраски. Вы же не сможете передать голосом одновременно вопрос и спокойную повествовательную интонацию? Точка поглощается вопросительным знаком. Следовательно, примеры 5, 6 верны. В 7 после кавычек точка не нужна, в 8, если хочется восклицание соединить с вопросом, оба знака поставить перед кавычками: *Пётр кричит в бездну мироздания: «Мечтают ли андроиды об электроовцах?!»,* в 9 вопрос после кавычек лишний, он уже есть в прямой речи.

**Не прямая речь**:

Вопросительный и восклицательный знаки и многоточие ставятся перед закрывающими кавычками, если относятся к словам, заключенным в кавычки:
*Роман «Кто виноват?» написан А. И. Герценом; Раздаётся возглас «ура!», а затем всё неожиданно стихает; «Я хочу поделиться с вами…» — так начал он свой рассказ.*

Если же вопросительный и восклицательный знаки и многоточие относятся ко всему предложению вместе со словами, заключенными в кавычки, то названные знаки ставятся после закрывающих кавычек:
*Не слишком ли часто на страницах газет встречаются шаблонные выражения «чёрное золото», «белое золото», «мягкое золото»?; Надоело мне ваше «За ответом приходите завтра»!; Он так и не закончил фразу: «Прежде чем приступите к чтению „Евгения Онегина“…*

Если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит вопросительный или восклицательный знак, то после кавычек он не повторяется:
*Читали ли вы роман «Что делать?»*

Неодинаковые же знаки, если они требуются по условиям контекста, ставятся перед закрывающими кавычками и после них:
*Я читаю роман А. И. Герцена «Кто виноват?».*
*В каком стихотворении М. Ю. Лермонтова есть слова: «Люблю Отчизну я, но странною любовью!»?*

Так что в примере 3 после кавычек точка. 1, 2 - верно.

---

**UPD.**

Если это прямая речь, знак конца СОВПАДАЕТ с эмоциональной окраской, а окраска диктуется прямой речью, Вы не произнесёте вопросительно-восклицательно конец, как бы ни желали. Если хотите непременно указать на восклицательно-восхищающуюся интонацию, переделайте в косвенную речь:
*Ух-ты, Пётр всё-таки спросил, выйдет ли она за него!*

В 7.1 после кавычек нет точки, в 9.1 тоже следует употребить косвенную речь:
*Пётр спрашивал у Фёдора, мечтают ли андроиды об электроовцах?* –
Так что способ есть - использование косвенной речи.

Передача чужой речи может быть оформлена как предложение с прямой и косвенной речью. Эмоциональная окраска и вопросительная интонация в предложении с косвенной речью касается всего предложения, чего Вы и добивались. Если же предложение с прямой речью, знаком конца будет передана интонация прямой речи, которая заключает предложение.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ и дополнение! Остаётся только вопрос про различение на письме не чужой речи (2) и (3) — по вашему ответу (3) превращается в (2).

Comment: В примере *Он так и не закончил фразу...* закрывающей кавычки быть не должно или это опечатка?

Comment: Да,(3) превращается в (2). Закрывающие кавычки, конечно, должны быть - такой же конфигурации, как и открывающие, чтобы отличить фразу от цитаты, многоточие после кавычек.